# How to compute the distance from the start of a polyline to a specific point on a map using maplibre?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, react-map-gl, maplibre-gl

I use `maplibregl` to display a map with a path (set of coordinates represented by a polyline). I want to compute the distance from the start of the polyline to any point hovered by the user, like on this screenshot:

[image]

What method can I use to get the polyline distance on mouseover?

Here is what I would like to do:

```js
map.on('mousemove', 'lineLayerHover', (e) => {
   const lineLayerFeatures = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point).filter((feature) => {
      return feature.layer.id === 'lineLayerHover';
   });

   const distanceFromPolylineStart = lineLayerFeatures[0].geometry.distanceFromPolylineStart;

   console.log(distanceFromPolylineStart);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41668577/distance-between-two-points-over-a-path-with-turf-js

Comment: Thanks you @AnatoliiSuhanov, it works perfectly!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Distance between two points over a path with turf.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41668577/distance-between-two-points-over-a-path-with-turf-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank to Anatolii's answer, here is the working solution using `turf` library:

```js
const traceLine = turf.lineString(routeCoordinates);
const traceStartPoint = turf.point(routeCoordinates[0]);

map.on('mousemove', 'traceLayerHover', (e) => {

   const hoveredPoint = turf.point(e.lngLat.toArray());

   const traceSliced = turf.lineSlice(traceStartPoint, hoveredPoint, traceLine);
   
const distanceFromStart = turf.length(traceSliced, { units: 'kilometers' });

   console.log("distance from start", distanceFromStart);
});
```